# Tkinter/ttk - treeview does not take up the full frame

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm trying out my first application in Tkinter/ttk.  I'm running into a minor formatting problem that I am unable to resolve.  I'm creating a tree view of a list of stock symbols in a frame.  When I run the application only the first 10 symbols are displayed in the table although the frame is large enough to display all 20 symbols in the list.  I have to scroll down to see the rest of the list.  I've researched other answers, but nothing seems to give the correct answer.  I also tried different combinations of sticky, fill, align, and height settings without success.  Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do to get the tree to fill up the frame?

Here is a minimal version of the code which shows the issue.  A png of the output is attached.

Thanks for your help!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ss:
    def __init__(self, root):
        left_frame = tk.Frame(root, height = 8000, width = 1000)
        right_frame = tk.Frame(root, height = 5000, width = 1000)
        left_top = tk.Frame(left_frame, height = 300, width = 1000)
        left_bottom = tk.Frame(left_frame, height = 2000)

        left_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'ns')
        right_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')
        left_top.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'ew')
        left_bottom.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'sew')
        left_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)


        tk.Label(left_top, text = "Sort by:").grid(row = 0, column = 0)


        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(left_bottom, selectmode = 'browse')
        self.tree.pack(side = 'left', expand = 1, fill = 'both')

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(left_bottom, orient = "vertical", command = self.tree.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side = 'left', expand = 1, fill = 'y')

        self.current_symbol = ""
        self.stock_label = tk.Label(right_frame,  text = self.current_symbol, anchor = 'n')
        self.stock_label.pack(side = 'top')

        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
        self.tree\["columns"\] = ("1")
        self.tree\['show'\] = 'headings'
        self.tree.column("1", width = 100, anchor = 'w')

        self.tree.heading("1", text = "Symbol", anchor = 'w')

        for row in range(0, 20):
            symbol = "Stock" + str(row)
            self.tree.insert("", 'end', text=symbol, values = (symbol))


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Stock Screener")
    root.geometry("2000x1000")
    ss(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to expand row=0 of the root window. To let the left frame expand NS. And you forgot to expand `left_bottom` in the `n` direction.

```
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1) # configure the root grid rows
left_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'ns')
right_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')
left_top.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'ew')
left_bottom.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew') # here add 'n'
left_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for the quick solution.